# Why can't Ubuntu find any hard disks or volumes during installation?

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, windows, hard-drive

I decided to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer. But when I try to install Ubuntu 13.04, my installation says I don't have atleast 5.3 GB disk space. In "Try ubuntu", I checked disks utility, System monitor and gParted, none of them list my Hard Disks ( I have 2 hard disks, 1 is 80GB, the other is 500 GB, both are mostly empty and IDE). My Windows 7 works, and detects all the hard disks ( so this may not be a h/w problem )

I have tried a few ways to resolve this, but have failed.
Note : I have checked this website and there are a few questions exactly like mine, but none have been adequately answered so as to solve my problem.
Here are some terminal results

sudo dmesg - ( this thing is long )

```
    [    0.128378] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.PEX0._PRT]
    [    0.128434] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.PEX1._PRT]
    [    0.128484] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.PEX2._PRT]
    [    0.128533] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.PEX3._PRT]
    [    0.128581] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Routing Table [\_SB_.PCI0.HUB0._PRT]
    [    0.128800]  pci0000:00: ACPI _OSC support notification failed, disabling PCIe     ASPM
    [    0.128803]  pci0000:00: Unable to request _OSC control (_OSC support mask: 0x08)
    [    0.130120] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 *10 11 12 14 15)
    [    0.130191] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 *11 12 14 15)
    [    0.130260] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 *9 10 11 12 14 15)
    [    0.130328] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12 14 *15)
    [    0.130396] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12 14 15) *0,     disabled.
    [    0.130466] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12 14 15) *0,     disabled.
    [    0.130536] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNK0] (IRQs 3 4 5 7 9 10 11 12 14 15) *0,     disabled.
    [    0.130606] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNK1] (IRQs 3 4 *5 7 9 10 11 12 14 15)
    [    0.132020] vgaarb: device added:         PCI:0000:00:02.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
    [    0.132028] vgaarb: loaded
    [    0.132030] vgaarb: bridge control possible 0000:00:02.0
    [    0.132369] SCSI subsystem initialized
    [    0.132373] ACPI: bus type scsi registered
    [    0.132388] libata version 3.00 loaded.
    [    0.132388] ACPI: bus type usb registered
    [    0.132388] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.132388] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.132388] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    0.132388] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
    [    0.141956] PCI: pci_cache_line_size set to 64 bytes
    [    0.142037] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x0009f400-0x0009ffff]
    [    0.142040] e820: reserve RAM buffer [mem 0x5f590000-0x5fffffff]
    [    0.142182] NetLabel: Initializing
    [    0.142185] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
    [    0.142187] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4
    [    0.142202] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
    [    0.142222] HPET: 3 timers in total, 0 timers will be used for per-cpu timer
    [    0.142222] hpet0: at MMIO 0xfed00000, IRQs 2, 8, 0
    [    0.142222] hpet0: 3 comparators, 64-bit 14.318180 MHz counter
    [    0.144021] Switching to clocksource hpet
    [    0.158967] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
    [    0.159020] pnp: PnP ACPI init
    [    0.159047] ACPI: bus type pnp registered
    [    0.159308] system 00:00: [io  0x04d0-0x04d1] has been reserved
    [    0.159315] system 00:00: [io  0x0800-0x087f] has been reserved
    [    0.159321] system 00:00: [io  0x0880-0x088f] has been reserved
    [    0.159329] system 00:00: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
    [    0.159355] pnp 00:01: [dma 4]
    [    0.159402] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
    [    0.159566] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active)
    [    0.159653] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
    [    0.159706] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0800 (active)
    [    0.159770] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active)
    [    0.160151] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
    [    0.160512] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0501 (active)
    [    0.161028] pnp 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0400 (active)
    [    0.161229] pnp 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0f13 (active)
    [    0.161325] pnp 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0303 PNP030b (active)
    [    0.161445] system 00:0b: [io  0x0400-0x04bf] has been reserved
    [    0.161453] system 00:0b: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
    [    0.161526] pnp 00:0c: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs INT0800 (active)
    [    0.161947] system 00:0d: [mem 0xe0000000-0xefffffff] has been reserved
    [    0.161955] system 00:0d: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
    [    0.162178] system 00:0e: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff] could not be reserved
    [    0.162185] system 00:0e: [mem 0x5f600000-0x5f6fffff] has been reserved
[       0.162191] system 00:0e: [mem 0xfed00000-0xfed000ff] has been reserved
[    0.162197] system 00:0e: [mem 0x5f590000-0x5f5fffff] could not be reserved
[    0.162202] system 00:0e: [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff] could not be reserved
[    0.162208] system 00:0e: [mem 0x00100000-0x5f58ffff] could not be reserved
[    0.162214] system 00:0e: [mem 0xfec00000-0xfec00fff] could not be reserved
[    0.162220] system 00:0e: [mem 0xfed13000-0xfed1dfff] has been reserved
[    0.162226] system 00:0e: [mem 0xfed20000-0xfed8ffff] has been reserved
[    0.162232] system 00:0e: [mem 0xfee00000-0xfee00fff] has been reserved
[    0.162237] system 00:0e: [mem 0xffb00000-0xffb7ffff] has been reserved
[    0.162243] system 00:0e: [mem 0xfff00000-0xffffffff] has been reserved
[    0.162249] system 00:0e: [mem 0x000e0000-0x000effff] has been reserved
[    0.162256] system 00:0e: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c01 (active)
[    0.162269] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 15 devices
[    0.162272] ACPI: ACPI bus type pnp unregistered
[    0.162279] PnPBIOS: Disabled by ACPI PNP
[    0.200273] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    0.200280] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [io  0xb000-0xbfff]
[    0.200288] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfd400000-0xfd4fffff]
[    0.200294] pci 0000:00:1c.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200302] pci 0000:00:1c.1: PCI bridge to [bus 02]
[    0.200307] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [io  0xa000-0xafff]
[    0.200313] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [mem 0xfdd00000-0xfddfffff]
[    0.200319] pci 0000:00:1c.1:   bridge window [mem 0xfdc00000-0xfdcfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200327] pci 0000:00:1c.2: PCI bridge to [bus 03]
[    0.200332] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    0.200338] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdbfffff]
[    0.200344] pci 0000:00:1c.2:   bridge window [mem 0xfda00000-0xfdafffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200352] pci 0000:00:1c.3: PCI bridge to [bus 04]
[    0.200357] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.200363] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xfd900000-0xfd9fffff]
[    0.200369] pci 0000:00:1c.3:   bridge window [mem 0xfd800000-0xfd8fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200377] pci 0000:00:1e.0: PCI bridge to [bus 05]
[    0.200381] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    0.200388] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfd600000-0xfd6fffff]
[    0.200394] pci 0000:00:1e.0:   bridge window [mem 0xfd500000-0xfd5fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200455] pci 0000:00:1e.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    0.200461] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.200464] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.200468] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.200471] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 7 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.200475] pci_bus 0000:00: resource 8 [mem 0x5f600000-0xfebfffff]
[    0.200479] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 0 [io  0xb000-0xbfff]
[    0.200482] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 1 [mem 0xfd400000-0xfd4fffff]
[    0.200486] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 2 [mem 0xfde00000-0xfdefffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200490] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 0 [io  0xa000-0xafff]
[    0.200493] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 1 [mem 0xfdd00000-0xfddfffff]
[    0.200497] pci_bus 0000:02: resource 2 [mem 0xfdc00000-0xfdcfffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200501] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 0 [io  0xe000-0xefff]
[    0.200504] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0xfdb00000-0xfdbfffff]
[    0.200508] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 2 [mem 0xfda00000-0xfdafffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200511] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 0 [io  0xd000-0xdfff]
[    0.200515] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 1 [mem 0xfd900000-0xfd9fffff]
[    0.200519] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 2 [mem 0xfd800000-0xfd8fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200522] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 0 [io  0xc000-0xcfff]
[    0.200526] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 1 [mem 0xfd600000-0xfd6fffff]
[    0.200529] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 2 [mem 0xfd500000-0xfd5fffff 64bit pref]
[    0.200533] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 4 [io  0x0000-0x0cf7]
[    0.200536] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 5 [io  0x0d00-0xffff]
[    0.200540] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 6 [mem 0x000a0000-0x000bffff]
[    0.200543] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 7 [mem 0x000c0000-0x000dffff]
[    0.200547] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 8 [mem 0x5f600000-0xfebfffff]
[    0.200597] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.200876] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.200920] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.200960] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.200996] TCP: reno registered
[    0.201001] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.201016] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.201116] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.201140] pci 0000:00:02.0: Boot video device
[    0.201325] PCI: CLS 32 bytes, default 64
[    0.201398] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[   10.692661] Freeing initrd memory: 21568k freed
[   10.706208] Initialise module verification
[   10.706286] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
[   10.706307] type=2000 audit(1372874756.700:1): initialized
[   10.738544] bounce pool size: 64 pages
[   10.738562] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[   10.740772] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
[   10.740849] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[   10.741673] fuse init (API version 7.20)
[   10.741794] msgmni has been set to 1729
[   10.742311] Key type asymmetric registered
[   10.742315] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[   10.742373] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[   10.742409] io scheduler noop registered
[   10.742413] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[   10.742425] io scheduler cfq registered
[   10.742624] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: irq 40 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.742743] pcieport 0000:00:1c.1: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.742857] pcieport 0000:00:1c.2: irq 42 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.742970] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.743069] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
[   10.743097] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   10.743206] intel_idle: does not run on family 6 model 15
[   10.743300] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0
[   10.743308] ACPI: Power Button [PWRB]
[   10.743379] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1
[   10.743384] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[   10.743505] ACPI: Requesting acpi_cpufreq
[   10.747494] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
[   10.747526] isapnp: Scanning for PnP cards...
[   10.752074] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 32 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[   10.772550] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[   10.793060] 00:07: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[   10.795333] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[   10.795500] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: Intel G33 Chipset
[   10.795578] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected gtt size: 524288K total, 262144K mappable
[   10.796022] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: detected 8192K stolen memory
[   10.796189] agpgart-intel 0000:00:00.0: AGP aperture is 256M @ 0xd0000000
[   10.798495] brd: module loaded
[   10.799764] loop: module loaded
[   10.799986] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.1: version 2.13
[   10.800080] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.1: setting latency timer to 64
[   10.800534] scsi0 : ata_piix
[   10.801120] scsi1 : ata_piix
[   10.801441] ata1: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xfa00 irq 14
[   10.801447] ata2: PATA max UDMA/100 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xfa08 irq 15
[   10.801480] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: MAP [
[   10.801483]  P0 P2 P1 P3 ]
[   10.801535] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
[   10.801929] scsi2 : ata_piix
[   10.802321] scsi3 : ata_piix
[   10.802661] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xf900 ctl 0xf800 bmdma 0xf500 irq 19
[   10.802666] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0xf700 ctl 0xf600 bmdma 0xf508 irq 19
[   10.803203] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[   10.803312] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[   10.803315] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[   10.803383] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[   10.803440] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[   10.803443] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[   10.803482] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: setting latency timer to 64
[   10.803488] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: EHCI Host Controller
[   10.803497] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[   10.803514] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: debug port 1
[   10.807423] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: cache line size of 32 is not supported
[   10.807450] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: irq 23, io mem 0xfdfff000
[   10.807696] ata2: port disabled--ignoring
[   10.816024] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.7: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[   10.816066] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   10.816072] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   10.816077] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[   10.816082] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic ehci_hcd
[   10.816087] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.7
[   10.816277] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   10.816289] hub 1-0:1.0: 8 ports detected
[   10.816563] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[   10.816582] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[   10.816621] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[   10.816661] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   10.816667] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: UHCI Host Controller
[   10.816677] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[   10.816709] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io base 0x0000fe00
[   10.816758] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[   10.816764] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   10.816769] usb usb2: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[   10.816773] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic uhci_hcd
[   10.816778] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[   10.816943] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   10.816952] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[   10.817089] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: setting latency timer to 64
[   10.817096] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: UHCI Host Controller
[   10.817105] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[   10.817138] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.1: irq 19, io base 0x0000fd00
[   10.817186] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[   10.817191] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   10.817196] usb usb3: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[   10.817201] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic uhci_hcd
[   10.817206] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.1
[   10.817348] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   10.817354] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[   10.817496] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: setting latency timer to 64
[   10.817502] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: UHCI Host Controller
[   10.817512] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[   10.817563] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.2: irq 18, io base 0x0000fc00
[   10.817611] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[   10.817617] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   10.817622] usb usb4: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[   10.817626] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic uhci_hcd
[   10.817631] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.2
[   10.817801] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   10.817810] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[   10.817943] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: setting latency timer to 64
[   10.817950] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: UHCI Host Controller
[   10.817959] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 5
[   10.818004] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.3: irq 16, io base 0x0000fb00
[   10.818055] usb usb5: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[   10.818060] usb usb5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   10.818065] usb usb5: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[   10.818070] usb usb5: Manufacturer: Linux 3.8.0-19-generic uhci_hcd
[   10.818075] usb usb5: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.3
[   10.818240] hub 5-0:1.0: USB hub found
[   10.818247] hub 5-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[   10.818510] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[   10.821116] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[   10.821128] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[   10.821319] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[   10.821469] rtc_cmos 00:03: RTC can wake from S4
[   10.821599] rtc_cmos 00:03: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[   10.821628] rtc0: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[   10.821774] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[   10.821859] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.23.1-ioctl (2012-12-18) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[   10.821886] EISA: Probing bus 0 at eisa.0
[   10.821890] EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[   10.821893] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[   10.821896] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[   10.821898] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[   10.821901] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[   10.821903] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[   10.821906] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[   10.821908] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[   10.821911] Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[   10.821913] EISA: Detected 0 cards.
[   10.821926] cpufreq-nforce2: No nForce2 chipset.
[   10.821929] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[   10.821931] cpuidle: using governor menu
[   10.821938] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[   10.821940] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[   10.822172] ashmem: initialized
[   10.822399] TCP: cubic registered
[   10.822598] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[   10.822955] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[   10.822972] Key type dns_resolver registered
[   10.823301] Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
[   10.823433] Loading module verification certificates
[   10.831008] MODSIGN: Loaded cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: fceb9fd088cf158e29d83343e1c98bf8ab23d94a'
[   10.831031] registered taskstats version 1
[   10.835051] Key type trusted registered
[   10.839070] Key type encrypted registered
[   10.843365] rtc_cmos 00:03: setting system clock to 2013-07-03 18:05:57 UTC (1372874757)
[   10.843830] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[   10.843834] EDD information not available.
[   10.849869] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[   10.984399] ata1.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-STDVD-RAM GH22NP20, 1.03, max UDMA/66
[   10.984423] ata1.01: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST GCE-8527B, 1.02, max UDMA/33
[   11.000261] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/66
[   11.048217] ata1.01: configured for UDMA/33
[   11.101005] isapnp: No Plug & Play device found
[   11.102214] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GH22NP20 1.03 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   11.103973] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 125x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[   11.103978] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[   11.104167] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[   11.104310] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
[   11.106319] scsi 0:0:1:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST CD-RW GCE-8527B  1.02 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[   11.108913] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 52x/52x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[   11.109078] sr 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[   11.109205] sr 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[   11.128043] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   11.279021] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0ac8, idProduct=3450
[   11.279027] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   11.279032] usb 1-4: Product: see me here
[   11.279037] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: see me here
[   11.704025] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 1591.107 MHz
[   11.704033] Switching to clocksource tsc
[   16.000018] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   20.816019] ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   26.012017] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   30.828019] ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   36.024016] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   65.872022] ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   70.900022] ata3: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   70.910713] ata3: reset failed, giving up
[   70.910807] Freeing unused kernel memory: 784k freed
[   70.911109] Write protecting the kernel text: 6252k
[   70.911214] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 2432k
[   70.911216] NX-protecting the kernel data: 3988k
[   70.933314] udevd[108]: starting version 175
[   71.031144] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   71.060859] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   71.081024] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[   71.081243] r8169 0000:02:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   71.081487] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8102e at 0xf840c000, 00:e0:4c:1e:9d:9e, XID 04c00000 IRQ 44
[   71.137892] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
[   71.138238] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[   71.138254] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 1 (10.10.2010).
[   71.138257] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   71.138299] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[   71.143241] [drm] initialized overlay support
[   71.314278] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   71.370428] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
[   71.376602] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   71.376606] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[   71.376657] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   81.414780] xor: automatically using best checksumming function:
[   81.452006]    pIII_sse  :  5780.000 MB/sec
[   81.462230] device-mapper: dm-raid45: initialized v0.2594b
[   82.203377] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[   82.217983] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
[   82.655982] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[  131.040182] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  131.761365] udevd[1111]: starting version 175
[  134.704042] init: avahi-cups-reload main process (1150) terminated with status 1
[  135.121892] microcode: CPU0 sig=0x6fd, pf=0x1, revision=0xa3
[  135.162470] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[  135.167111] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[  135.167174] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[  135.167177] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  135.167187] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  135.167192] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  135.167202] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  136.038669] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  136.038692] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  136.038695] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  136.059898] intel_rng: FWH not detected
[  137.710747] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[  137.740072] microcode: CPU1 sig=0x6fd, pf=0x1, revision=0xa3
[  137.753131] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.00 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
[  138.139774] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=10 00 64, EC=10 00 64
[  138.385134] parport_pc 00:08: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[  138.385192] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
[  138.480199] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[  138.840033] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
[  139.022137] ACPI Warning: 0x00000428-0x0000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PM2S 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[  139.022149] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[  139.022155] ACPI Warning: 0x000004b0-0x000004bf SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPO2 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[  139.022161] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[  139.022164] ACPI Warning: 0x00000480-0x000004af SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPO_ 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[  139.022170] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[  139.022173] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[  139.480556] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
[  139.480584] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
[  139.615313] input: ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3
```

sudo fdisk -l lists nothing

Comment: I have shaved some portion from the top and bottom from my demsg code as I was not allowed more than 30,000 characters..

Comment: Under the disk management console in Windows are your disks marked as dynamic? If they made into dynamic volumes by Windows then they will not probably be detected.

Comment: okay, checking that.

Comment: "[   70.910713] ata3: reset failed, giving up" does not look good... Probably it will not help, but I'd try to switch the 2 IDE cables on the mainboard. Some OS' (ok, I think this only applies to Windows 9x, but checking won't hurt) don't like it, if the first IDE device is a CD drive. Also, I'd double check if the master/slave jumpers are set correctly on your HDDs and in doubt switch from "cable select" to explicit Master and Slave assignment.

Comment: all my partitions are dynamic volumes.

Comment: @AJha then you have solved the puzzle... :)

Comment: Well, let me check if I can convert them to basic format without losing my data. Will report back then..

Comment: **Make backups!**

Comment: Did convert to basic disk. Still cannot see any hard drives. Can't install, because installer says there is not enough space ( atleast 5.3 GB is required)

Comment: So I doubt if dynamic disks were the problem..

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not work well with dynamic disks volumes created by Windows and fails most of the time to detect them.

The only known solutions there are to install Ubuntu in such disks are to convert them back to basic or install Ubuntu in another disk that has not been converted.

More information about the tools you need and procedures to take to convert a disk to a basic volume [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1705481).

Comment: My motherboard is a mercury.. can it be the source of the problem ?

Comment: This didn't solve the problem. What can I do?

Comment: Changed my disks to basic disk, still not able to install

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with the drive or the controller as they won't reset and initialize correctly.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying, but if you are saying there may be a problem with the hard disk, then even the windows installations should not work, but it works..

Comment: @AJha, Windows doesn't reset the controller so doesn't trigger the problem.  Try booting with the argument "libata.force=norst" to see if that fixes it.  At the boot menu press F6 to edit the kernel command line and add that argument.

Comment: tried booting with libata.force=norst . Didnt work

Answer (score 1):

The issue maybe the partition table, however there are minimal chances of this as Windows is working fine.

My guess is that you're using your HDDs as 'Dynamic Disks' in Windows. The best (and probably the only sane) resolution is:

1. Backup ALL your drives to another HDD (which is Basic). Contact a friend (or foe) if you need. [You may also boot into Windows and copy all data from partitions of Drive1 to those of Drive2. And then disconnect Drive2 when you install Ubuntu.]
2. Boot into Windows now, and convert the drive to Basic (convert both drives if you backed it up to a 3rd drive; or only Drive1 if the backup is on Drive2).
3. Delete all partitions on the drive (to be foolproof).
4. Install Windows, AND then, Ubuntu. (Avoid extended partitions if you can, they've messed my partition table in the past.)

Can't reinstall Windows?
Okay! Then say Disk1 has Windows installed, copy contents of Disk2 to Disk1. And convert Disk2 to Basic. Install Ubuntu on Disk2. Make Disk2 the default boot-device from the BIOS. And final step is to do `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I have already changed my disks into basic disks... and unluckily it hasn't helped me

Comment: Do you have a backup of your data? If yes, delete all partitions of any one drive, disconnect the other drive from the MoBo (as a precaution), and try installation again.

Answer (score 0):

yep., that is may be getting into account while you are installing ubuntu from boot because it doesn't support dynamic disk volumes with formats .NTFS and .GTP etc.., but did you ever tried to start ubuntu installation from the windows it self and when you doing like this it may ask you to choose which Drive you want to install ubuntu and how much memory you want to use for OS and which version do you want to install all these options are available with this mode of installation.., checked it out once.

Answer (score 0):

My friend also reported this problem today, that Ubuntu was not able to detect the partitions, while Windows installer detected.

I told him to try out different Linux Live CDs to check if the problem persists, but he had success with Linux Mint which could read his partitions.

So you could download Ubuntu 12.04.3(LTS), and try it also, otherwise you could also try Linux Mint to see if its detecting your disks.

Perhaps theres a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I did try with 12.04(LTS), but it didnt work either. Will try linux mint too, but I want to install ubuntu, not mint.